# Android extracting id3 tag information

Tags: java, android, id3, http-live-streaming

I have a HLS stream which I am displaying using the native android media player. I need to be able to extract id3tags that are pushed through the stream every 30 seconds. I have had a good dig around the internet and have not found a viable method for doing this.

I did find something called [MediaPlayer.OnTimedMetaDataAvailableListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnTimedMetaDataAvailableListener.html) but this is only available on sdk 23 and I need to support down to 14. Has anyone managed to extract these tags from a HLS stream on android? Or does anyone have any idea about how to go about it?

Comment: `this is only available on sdk 23` Maybe it is also available to older devices by using the various support libraries?

Comment: Quite possibly I will investigate.

Comment: I cannot find anything in the appcompat libraries.

Comment: We're planning to add it to our HLS lib - https://github.com/kaltura/Android-HLS-lib - if you wish you may open a pull :-)

Comment: Cool looking project! Did you guys manage to overcome the issues with playing HSL on 5.0? Would love to help you out, I'll see if I get time at the end of this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet using the standard MediaPlayer. According to the [Android Developer API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html), it is recommended to use the [ExoPlayer](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/) when utilizing features such as id3 tag reading of HLS. There is a great demo on GitHub to help you get started.You basically create a Player and add a listener to it:

```
player.setMetadataListener(this);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I have switched to the exoplayer and it is working great :)

Comment: Sorry got caught up. Thanks again :P Also exo-player seems to solve HSL playback issues on android 5.0... if anyone is interested!